# Under what conditions does RmGetList return 2 for the lpdwRebootReasons output parameter?

Tags: winapi, cygwin, inno-setup, restartmanager, windows-restart-manager

## Background

I am designing an Inno Setup installer to install a [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) service, and I am puzzled by the behavior I'm seeing from the Windows [Restart Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_rstmgr/) APIs.

Specifically, when the service is running (started using the `cygrunsrv` utility), the [RmGetList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/restartmanager/nf-restartmanager-rmgetlist) API function returns 2 (`RmRebootReasonSessionMismatch`) for its `lpdwRebootReasons` output parameter. This output parameter is an enumeration of type [`RM_REBOOT_REASON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/restartmanager/ne-restartmanager-rm_reboot_reason), and the description on MSDN for the `RmRebootReasonSessionMismatch` value is:

```
One or more processes are running in another Terminal Services session.
```

The Inno Setup log file contains lines like the following:

```
RestartManager found an application using one of our files: <executable name>
RestartManager found an application using one of our files: <service name>
Can use RestartManager to avoid reboot? No (2: Session Mismatch)
```

Inno Setup then proceeds trying to replace in-use files, as if Restart Manager was not used at all.

I am puzzled by this output value, because on two different machines I tested (Windows 10 1909 x64 and Windows Server 2012 R2), no terminal server/remote desktop users are logged on.

If I stop the service and start another executable (in the set of files to be replaced by the installer), RmGetList returns 0 (`RmRebootReasonNone`) for `lpdwRebootReasons`, and Inno Setup displays the normal dialog for in-use files and allows the user to select to automatically close them.

[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) shows both processes (`cygrunsrv.exe` and the process it starts) running in session 0 and at `System` integrity level. Both are console subsystem executables.

## Questions

1. Under what conditions does RmGetList return 2 (`RmRebootReasonSessionMismatch`) for its `lpdwRebootReasons` output parameter? (I'm trying to understand why this happens when the service is running.)
2. Does this value cause the entire Restart Manager session to fail, or can Restart Manager proceed even though it thinks applications are running in one or more different sessions?

Comment: Note that services are running in session 0. Does the Process you've got from `RM_PROCESS_INFO` run in another session? You could run `tasklist` in cmd to check the process&session info.

Comment: See update. The processes (both `cygrunsrv` and the process it starts) run at `System` integrity level in session 0. Both are console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A Clue from the RestartManager PowerShell Module

The [RestartManager PowerShell module](https://github.com/heaths/RestartManager) (special thanks to [Heath Stewart](https://github.com/heaths)) provides a simple PowerShell interface for the Restart Manager. My commands are as follows:

```
Set-Location <path to Cygwin root directory>
Start-RestartManagerSession
Get-ChildItem . -File -Include *.exe,*.dll -Recurse | RegisterRestartManagerResource
Get-RestartManagerProcess
Stop-RestartManagerProcess
```

These commands produce the following output:

```
Id                : <process ID>
StartTime         : <process start time>
Description       : <executable started by cygrunsrv>
ServiceName       :
ApplicationType   : Console
ApplicationStatus : Running
IsRestartable     : False
RebootReason      : SessionMismatch

Id                : <cygrunsrv process id>
StartTime         : <cygrunsrv process start time>
Description       : <description of service>
ServiceName       : <service name>
ApplicationType   : Service
ApplicationStatus : Running
IsRestartable     : True
RebootReason      : SessionMismatch
```

For some reason, Restart Manager sees the `cygrunsrv.exe` service process as restartable, but the executable it spawns as not restartable. (I am still curious about why this happens in the first place.)

## An Imperfect Workaround Attempt

Based on this observed behavior, I first attempted the following workaround:

1. In the Inno Setup script's `[Setup]` section, set the following:

   ```
    CloseApplications=yes
    CloseApplicationsFilter=*.chm,*.pdf
    RestartApplications=yes
   ```

   The [`CloseApplicationsFilter`](https://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_closeapplicationsfilter) directive specifies what files get registered with the Restart Manager. Note I do not specify `*.exe` or `*.dll` here; I want to manually specify only certain `.exe` files in the `[Code]` section.
2. Call the Inno Setup [`RegisterExtraCloseApplicationsResource`](https://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_registerextracloseapplicationsresource) function once for each `.exe` file in the setup that will NOT be spawned by `cygrunsrv` and put them in the `RegisterExtraCloseApplicationsResources` event procedure. Example:

   ```
    [Code]

    procedure RegisterExtraCloseApplicationsResources();
    begin
      RegisterExtraCloseApplicationsResource(false, ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\cygrunsrv.exe'));
    end;
   ```

It's important not to register any executable spawned by `cygrunsrv.exe` or any of the Cygwin DLL files, because this will prevent the Restart Manager from taking effect in Inno Setup.

This solution is far from perfect, because executables normally started by `cygrunsrv`, if started separately, are not detected by Restart Manager (e.g., `sshd.exe`). For example, new SSH sessions are spawned in executables that the Restart Manager are not restartable.

## A Better Solution

I've decided that a better solution is to detect any running executables from code and prompt the user apart from the Restart Manager functionality (which, simply put, doesn't work for Cygwin services).

Answer (score 3):

For question 2, in the document [`RM_PROCESS_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/restartmanager/ns-restartmanager-rm_process_info)

> bRestartable
>
> **TRUE** if the application can be restarted by the Restart Manager;
>   otherwise, **FALSE**. This member is always **TRUE** if the process is a
>   service. This member is always **FALSE** if the process is a critical
>   system process.

This value indicates if the application can be restarted by the Restart Manager.

For question 1, Note that services are running in session 0. If the process occupying the resource (registered in `RmRegisterResources`) is a service A, the `RmGetList` function which also running in the service process B will return `lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonNone`, `bRestartable = TRUE`.

But if A is not a service, then A & B are running in different sessions, `lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonSessionMismatch` and `bRestartable = FALSE`

other results:(B run with elevated privileges)

- A & B is a console and in the same session：`lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonNone`, `bRestartable = TRUE`, `ApplicationType = RmConsole`.
- A & B is a console and in the different session：`lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonSessionMismatch`, `bRestartable = FALSE`, `ApplicationType = RmConsole`.
- A: service, B: console: `lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonNone`, `bRestartable = TRUE`, `ApplicationType = RmService`

(B not run with elevated privileges):

- A & B is a console and in the different session：`lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonCriticalProcess`, `bRestartable = FALSE`, `ApplicationType = RmCritical`.
- A: service, B: console: `lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonPermissionDenied`, `bRestartable = FALSE`, `ApplicationType = RmCritical`

According the document `bRestartable` depends on `ApplicationType`. And then, we can see that if the `bRestartable = TRUE`, then the `lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonNone`. But when `bRestartable = FALSE`, It depends on the other members `RM_PROCESS_INFO`.